# Saving and reassigning global variables dict in Python

Tags: python, jython, global

I'm working in a large Python codebase which has its own functions defined for running certain sections of code called "rules". We have these rules defined in a certain place, and to run them we call the following function with their name as an argument:

```py
runRule(<name of rule>)
```

Under the hood I don't know how it works, and don't have access to that information (sadly), but I think it does something like copying and pasting the rule code in the current position. I know it's not ideal and messy, but I don't have a choice but to work with it as it is.

My concern is that using `runRule` could potentially modify the local/global variables in the current namespace in an undesirable/unexpected way.

My question is whether something like the following code would make sense to avoid my concern?

```py
# (using deepcopy didn't work when I tried... so will have to settle for a shallow copy)
globals_temp = dict(globals())

runRule("my_edit_rule")

# restore globals to what it was before running the rule
globals().update(globals_temp)

# this was added to globals originally and is no longer needed
del globals()["globals_temp"]
```

I know it's yuck code, but it may be my only option given then codebase I'm working with...

Comment: That is really gross. If you really want to be sure it's not doing anything crazy, I would isolate this by running the function inside a subprocess. e.g. something like `subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-c", "runRule('my_edit_rule')"])`

Comment: `globals().copy()` would also work

Comment: tbh you can put this logic in a decorator, and call it a day.

Comment: I would be weary of using `globals` like this. If you don't know how `runRule` works under the hood you have no guarantee it doesn't depend on something in `globals`...

Comment: @rv.kvetch yes, I was planning on putting this all in a wrapper function, e.g. runRuleNew(<edit rule name>). Would `globals().copy()` be better than `dict(globals())`?

Comment: Good point @BTables. Perhaps I'll just have to continue without doing any of what I mentioned and always just make double sure the rules I use don't modify things that shouldn't be modified.

Comment: @flakes this was a good idea, but I think BTtables' comment stops me from evening doing what you mentioned.